# I have multiple checkboxes, and want to make a rule for 2 of them so that if I select 1 the other cannot be selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
​<form>
    <label for="1">Text 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="something1" id="1"><br>
    <label for="2">Text 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="something2" id="2"><br>
    <label for="3">Text 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="3" value="something3" id="3"><br>
    <label for="4">Text 4</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="4" value="something4" id="4">
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Those are the checkboxes , I have tried to search all over the internet and didn't find anything.

I want to allow the user to check  id 3 and 4 **BUT**  if he checks 1 , then 2 is not available to check, or if he checks 2 then 1 is not available to check.
And to the unavailable to add a class .. named .. 
      `grade-out{ color: #DDD;}`

Hope u understand the problem. Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Did try to use databinding on this?

Comment: First, is a bad practice use numbers to name or id

Comment: @user1646273 please, change name or id, ex. "1" to "checkBox1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add `data-groupid` attribute to your checkboxes to identify which group they belong to. And then add a click handler to checkboxes belonging to group, which would disable all other checkboxes in the same group when checked and enable them when unchecked..

Assumming your markup is consistent and labels are always predecessors of respective checkboxes, you can easily target them using the `prev()` method.

```
$('input:checkbox[data-group]').click(function() {

    var groupid = $(this).data('group');
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

    if(checked) {

        $('input:checkbox[data-group=' + groupid + ']').not($(this))
           .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
           .prev().addClass('grade-out');

    } else {

        $('input:checkbox[data-group=' + groupid + ']')
           .removeAttr('disabled')
           .prev().removeClass('grade-out');

    }

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PRXcR/2)

Comment: And one other thing.... The grade-out class I want to add it to the disabled input label

Comment: $('input:checkbox[data-group=' + groupid + ']')
        .not($(this)).attr('disabled', 'disabled').AddCss("grade-out")

Comment: @user1646273 see my updated answer.. I have also modified your numeric ids, since they are not valid

Answer (score 0):

You could use radio form inputs. Anyway, if it's a must to use checkboxes then you could use some javascript (with jQuery, for example)

```
$('#1,#2').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var theOtherId = $this.attr('id') == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    var theOtherOne = $('#'+theOtherId);
    if( $this.is(':checked') ) theOtherOne.attr('checked',false);
});
```

It this what you're looking for?

Re-worked example: [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taQCE/1/)

```
$('#1,#2').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var theOtherId = $this.attr('id') == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    var theOtherOne = $('#'+theOtherId);
    if( $this.is(':checked') ) theOtherOne.attr('disabled',true);
    else theOtherOne.attr('disabled',false);
});
```

Comment: 1 ? 2, should be "1" ? "2" as the id and name is treated as string, and $this is a bad choice for var name, use other please it confuses and uses a reserved word, please edit your response to fix it

Comment: $this isn't an error. Here is the (perfect) [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/taQCE/) (as I understood how it should work)

Comment: I edited my comment, yes I was wrong, is not an error, but is a bad naming alternative.

Comment: $this reffer to $(this). This notation is used by jQuery team to not redundantly wrap the `this` keyword in the immediate scope of your plugin's function. But why is a bad naming alternative? I can't see the "bad thing"...

Answer (score 0):

I would assign an attribute `data-disable` to disable certain elements and check `onchange`.

This is how I would do it:

```
<form>
    <label for="1">Text 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="something1" id="1" data-disable="2,3"><br>
    <label for="2">Text 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="something2" id="2" data-disable="1"><br>
    <label for="3">Text 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="3" value="something3" id="3"><br>
    <label for="4">Text 4</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="4" value="something4" id="4">
</form>​​​
```

and script:

```
$('input:checkbox​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​')​.on('change', function(){
    var toUncheck = $(this).attr('data-disable');
    var self = $(this);
        $.each(toUncheck.split(','), function(el, val){
            if(self.attr('checked') == 'checked'){
                $('#'+val).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                $('#'+val).removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
});​
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x9anV/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `$("#element_id").hide();` for disabling the check box
2. Use `$("#element_id").attr("checked", true);` to check if the check box is selected
3. Use `$("#element_id").addclass();` to add class to an element so in short search for jQuery selectors and you will find the solutions

Vist for more information http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ I hope I help take care

Answer (score 0):

Although there are more complex and flexible solutions above if you wish a solid but clear usage sample look at this. Using id's make things easier.

http://jsfiddle.net/erdincgc/uMhbs/1/

HTML (added class and id) ;

```
<form>
    <label for="1">Text 1</label>
        <input class="checks" type="checkbox"  id="option1"   name="option1"  value="something1" id="1"><br>
    <label for="2">Text 2</label>
        <input class="checks" type="checkbox"  id="option2"   name="option2" value="something2" id="2"><br>
    <label for="3">Text 3</label>
        <input class="checks" type="checkbox"  id="option3"   name="option3" value="something3" id="3"><br>
    <label for="4">Text 4</label>
        <input class="checks" type="checkbox"  id="option4"   name="option4" value="something4" id="4">
</form>
```

And JS

```
$('.checks').click(function(){
   op1 = $('#option1') ; 
   op2 = $('#option2') ;
   this_id = $(this).attr("id") ;
   this_state = $(this).attr("checked");

if(this_id =="option1"){
    if( this_state == "checked" ){
        op2.attr("disabled",true);            
    }
    else {
        op2.attr("disabled",false);
    }
    op2.prev().toggleClass('disabled'); 
} 

if(this_id=="option2"){
    if( this_state=="checked" ) 
        op1.attr("disabled",true); 
    else {
            op1.attr("disabled",false);
        }
        op1.prev().toggleClass('disabled');  
    }
});
```